# iOS AudioServicesAddSystemSoundCompletion callback incurring a 1 second delay

Tags: iphone, ios, audio, delay

I'm playing several sounds, and they have to be played in sequence (random), so that when one finishes, the next needs to start.

I'm using the AudioServicesAddSystemSoundCompletion callback procedure to determine when a sound file specified by a SystemSoundID has finished playing. At that point the static C callback method gets hit and then calls back into the instance to play another sound.

However, I'm getting a 1 second delay between the audio finishing and the callback function getting hit.

The audio is trimmed with no extra space at the end. I've put NSLog's in a few key places to confirm and the first sound is played - the rest of the code is doing nothing - just waiting for 'input' and then the callback gets hit routinely one second after the audio has finished.

I've looked in the official documentation and I can't find any reason for this - neither has 10 mins of googling offered any solution.

Anyone have any ideas please?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I do not know about the delay, I have never experienced that. But maybe you could try [this](https://github.com/CocoaMiners/AppSoundEngine). It is objective-c wrapper for SystemSoundID and some of its assosiated functionss, including completion callback. It should be easier to use this instead of C functions.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to those reading this, but I used a support request with Apple to get to the bottom of this due to time constraints and you wouldn't believe the answer...

There is NO delay. ( Spoon / whatever ;) )

The problem was caused by a UI 'feature' of the app we used to cut and trim and export the audio files...GarageBand.

It appears that if you trim an audio track in GarageBand until only the sound you want is visible and plays - even when looping - and then export that track as an .aif file... It puts WITHOUT SHOWING OR WARNING YOU - all of the trimmed and cut parts of the track BACK!!!

So that, even when you reopen the track in GB days later all you see and hear is the cut down trimmed version. However the trimming is just metadata on the file - just like iTunes trimming... Totally pointless.

So all the audio had to be re edited and exported in a more accurate audio app - audacity...

Apple did mention that the callback thread for these sound playbacks is a low priority thread, but that we still shouldn't have been seeing such a pause.

Thanks for those who tried to think of a reason, and in particular the poster above for taking the time to try and help.